# Socket_io_client chat count issue in flutter

Tags: flutter, sockets, flutter-dependencies

In flutter how can get number of unread message count in [Socket_io_client](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client) package ?

**like this is the way I m trying to print messages but it's not printed on console** :

```
  _socket.on(EVENT_UNREAD_COUNT, (message) {
       print(message);
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure our the issue basically issue was I

**Basically I was trying Socket.io server in v2 with v3 client basically this is compatible issue**

```
 To resolve this issue I degrade my socket_io_client package from           

 2.0.0 to 1.0.0 now its working fine.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have very specific issue with less explanation about your problem, like how your message feature work, how your messages will be stored and delivered, and what have you tried so far.

My first opinion about it for sure you need to stored "unread" status message somewhere, do it on API will be good options instead of socket

Comment: I updated my question please check now